# Polyharmonic Maass forms are automorphic forms on $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

Let $G=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, $K=\mathrm{SO}(2)$, and $f$ be a holomorphic modular form of weight $k$ for $\Gamma$ a Fuchsian group of the first kind. In Borel's book, 'automorphic forms on $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$', the lifted function $\tilde{f}$ is considered, where
$$
\tilde{f}(g)=j(g,i)^{-k}f(gi), \quad g \in G.
$$

In this book, a Lemma says that $f$ satisfies
$$
C\tilde{f}=(\frac{k^2}{2}-k)\tilde{f},
$$
where $C$ is the Casimir operator $C=\frac{1}{2}H^2+EF+FE$, $H=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}, E=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, F=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. This implies that $\tilde{f}$ is an automorphic form for $\Gamma$.

My first question is

1. Why the above lemma is true?

To ask the second question, let me define the polyharmonic maass forms. A polyharmonic maass form $f$ of weight $k$, depth $m$ for $\Gamma$ is a smooth function on $\mathbb{H}$ with the following properties:

(1). $f|_k \gamma (z) = f(z) \quad$ for $\gamma \in \Gamma$.

(2). $\Delta_k^m f =0 \quad$ where $\Delta_k=-y^2(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2})-iky(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial}{\partial y})$.

(3). moderate growth at the cusps

J.C.Lagarias and R.C.Rhoades' paper 'Polyharmonic Maass forms for $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$' says that the finite dimensionality of the space of polyharmonic maass forms follows from the finite dimensionality of the space of automorphic forms. Hence it seems that there is a natural embedding from polyharmonic maass forms to automorphic forms.

I guess that the same lift induce the natural linear embedding. If this true, then for a polyharmonic maass form $f$, there is a polynomial $P$ in $C$ such that

$$
P(C)\tilde{f}=0.
$$

2. Is my suggestion true?
3. If yes, what polynomial $P$ satisfies the above condition?

Comment: Please restrict to one question per post (standard MO policy). Your first question concerns Lemma 5.15 in Borel's book. The proof is included in the book, right below the lemma (it takes about one page).

Comment: GH from MO // The proof in the Borel's book is wrong. I resolved the questions, using different approach. Anyway, thank you for the comment.